# Creating a messaging "system" in DB (most especially MySQL)

Tags: database, mysql

I have a table successfully created in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MESSAGE
(
    MESSAGE_ID          BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT      
    ,AUTHOR_ID          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,TITLE              VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,MESSAGE            VARCHAR(4095) NOT NULL
    ,UNREAD_FLAG            BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE                   
    ,CREATION_DATE          TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,DATE_LAST_MODIFIED     TIMESTAMP NULL

    ,PRIMARY KEY (MESSAGE_ID)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (AUTHOR_ID) REFERENCES USER (USR_ID)
);
```

As you can see, there is no references to who receives the message(s) for the reason that 1 or more recipients can receive the same message.

1. How would I implement a message-threading "model" such that if there's a message that is sent to more than 1 user, the recipients can reply to the message and keep track on what message the recipient replied to? E.g. I've send a message to 5 friends about a party, and they all reply, how will I keep records on the response message link to the original message? Also, a recipient can also respond to a responded message, creating a response to a responded message, so eventually, it'll be a tree like structure of responded message.
2. How can I create a table to have more than 1 recipient receiving the same message? I had an idea of creating a table with recipient_id (reference to user table) and message_id (message id) pair. Is that efficient? The reason I ask is that if 200 people receive the same message, then there'll be 200 tables of user_id, message_id pair...

P.S. I've implemented number 2), so I guess that's not going to be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't understand your question here.
2. Your idea is the normal way to do this. You'd set up a table with recipient_id and message_id and run queries against it to determine (for instance) what messages a particular user has. You might also need to store additional data in this table like whether the user has read the message, etc., depending on the needs of your app.

Comment: For number 2, I did already that...thanks..I'm more worried about question 1. Notice that I've re-updated the question.

Comment: I would just add another column to your message table to track the response_to_id, which will be a foreign key back to message_id but can be null. If someone responds to message #123, their new message has its response_to_id set to 123. You can trace links back that way for responses to response and so on.

Comment: ok, will null foreign key be allowed? and does that make my table normalized?

Comment: Having nulls should be no problem. I do this in MySQL DBs all the time. I don't know about normalization, though; DB theory is not my forte.