# MySQL - Get last message from all users

Tags: mysql, database

I've searched on stackoverflow already, but the existing threads did not help me, so im posting this.

**My database schema:**

```
user: user_id, displayname
message: id, sender_id, receiver_id, message, dateSent
```

**What i want:**

Show me a list of the latest message from each user WHERE receiver_id = 4

**What i already tried:**

[MYSQL select newest posts from tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815116/mysql-select-newest-posts-from-tables)
[query to get last message only from all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541830/query-to-get-last-message-only-from-all-users)

Still can't solve my problem :(

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109449/creating-a-messaging-system-in-db-most-especially-mysql?rq=1

Comment: also what is id, sender_id, receiver_id in message. we need to know the relation back to 'user'

Comment: TRY this `SELECT m.*, u.* FROM user u inner join message m ON u.user_id=m.sender_id WHERE receiver_id=4` ....

Comment: sender_id -> user.user_id and receiver_id -> user.user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  u1.displayname AS SenderName,
  m.date_sent,
  ...
FROM messages AS m1
INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON m1.sender_id = u1.id
(
   SELECT sender_id, MAX(dateSent) MaxDate
   FROM messages 
   GROUP BY sender_id
   WHERE receiver_id = 4
) AS m2  ON m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id
        AND m1.datesent  = m2.maxdate
```

Comment: SELECT
  m1.*
FROM messages AS m1
INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON m1.sender_id = u1.id
(
   SELECT sender_id, MAX(dateSent) MaxDate
   FROM messages 
   GROUP BY sender_id
   WHERE receiver_id = 4
) AS m2  ON m1.id       = m2.id 
        AND m1.datesent = m2.maxdate

Comment: @CBergau - You forgot an `INNER JOIN` before the sub select it should be this `SELECT m1.* 
FROM messages AS m1 
INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON m1.sender_id = u1.id 
INNER JOIN 
( 
   SELECT sender_id, MAX(dateSent) MaxDate 
   FROM messages  
   GROUP BY sender_id WHERE receiver_id = 4 
) AS m2 ON m1.id = m2.id AND m1.datesent = m2.maxdate`

Comment: m2 has no id, i guess u mean m2.sender_id? This is what i got for now, but i get only 1 row as a result (3 expected) `SELECT m1.* 
FROM message AS m1 
INNER JOIN user 
AS u1 
ON m1.sender_id = u1.user_id 
INNER JOIN 
( 
SELECT sender_id, MAX(dateSent) MaxDate 
FROM message
WHERE receiver_id = 4 
GROUP BY sender_id 
) AS m2 ON m1.id = m2.sender_id 
AND m1.datesent = m2.maxdate`

Comment: @CBergau - Yes, join them using `sender_id`: `SELECT m1.* 
FROM message AS m1 
INNER JOIN user AS u1 ON m1.sender_id = u1.user_id 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT sender_id, MAX(dateSent) MaxDate 
    FROM message 
   WHERE receiver_id = 4 GROUP BY sender_id 
) AS m2 ON m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id AND m1.datesent = m2.maxdate`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.displayname, m.message
FROM user u
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id, sender_id, receiver_id, message, MAX(dateSent) AS mdate
FROM message msg
WHERE receiver_id = 4
GROUP BY sender_id
) as m
ON u.user_id = m.sender_id AND u.dateSent = m.mdate
```

HTH

Comment: Sorry, where have you defined "us"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.id, MAX as mDate, m.sender_id, u.displayname
FROM message m
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.user_id = m.sender_id
WHERE m.receiver_id = 4
GROUP BY sender_id
```